# Rails Authentication with Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am trying to make a Jquery/Ajax post request to create a new user in my rails back end. I have my User mode set up as follows.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
    VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
    validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
    has_secure_password
    validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }
end
```

And in my controller I have my create method defined like this:

```
def create
    @user = User.new(params[user_params])    # Not the final implementation!
    if @user.save
      #TODO make view
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      #TODO make error messag 
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end
```

user params is set to accept password and email.

```
private

    def user_params
      params.permit(:email, :password)
    end
```

Now from the front end I am trying to sign up for a new user using Jquery/Ajax. 
I have my jquery code defined as below:

```
$("#signupBtn").click(function(){
  var email = $("#email_sup").val();
  var password = $("#p_sup").val();
  var passCon = $("#pc_sup").val();

  var d = {
    'email': email,
    'password': password
  };

  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/users",
      data: d    
    }).success(function(json){
        console.log("success", json);
  });
```

Pretty self explanatory Jquery call. Now here is my main problem, not sure why but I am getting a rollback transaction.

[image]

I can create records from the console, not sure why it is not able to create records. it would be really helpful if someone can point me to the error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a user with that email currently in your DB? It looks like it's finding a user with that email and the email-unique constraint is preventing the save.

Comment: The DB is empty. I just did a rails db:reset as well. Still its the same problem.

Comment: Your `d` variable doesn't have the password confirmation,  could that be the problem?

Comment: Building off of what @Gerry said, I think that your method `has_secure_password` may be preventing the save, either through no password confirmation or some other security measure.